# How to point asp.net web.config connections to a docker container for database connections?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docker

I'm trying to understand how we would accomplish the task of taking an asp.net 4 web application using the web.config for connection strings, and a sql server database housing persistent data and use these both in separate docker containers.

Now I can create a container of a sql server image mounting to a volume for persisted data and run that.
Next I can create a container of an iis image that uses web.config transforms for our main environments, dev, alpha, prod, but how do i get this image to still use the web.config somehow so I can use it off our main CI builds, but override the values when running the containers to point to the also just created and running db container mentioned above? I've read up on linking, but this doesn't appear to help me with the web.config dilemma.

I'm looking into docker-compose.yml files but it's not clear to me how the asp.net application would have those web.config values overridden just yet.

Could someone point me in a direction for this or help me see what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

User PowerShell to parse the SQL container connection string details (credentials and port), and then edit the webconfig file for the .NET app.